# Automatic boot Windows on Grub dual boot

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-8

I have setup a dual boot Windows 8 / Ubuntu 12.04, and everything is fine with that.

Only, as I use Windows mainly I would like the Grub bootloader to automatically boot up windows instead of Ubuntu, which is also useful when installing drivers.

Is this possible? To rearrange the priorities on Grub?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A tool is dedicated to customizing GRUB: GRUB-Customizer.
https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer